# Question about the chain rule and derivates.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, chain-rule

I've seen someone claim that $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x) => g'(-x) = f'(x) -(-1 * f'(x))$ by the chain rule.
I just can't grasp my head around why is this true?

Comment: Thet's not tru. Perhaps you're thinking tha, if $g(x)=f(-x)$, then $g'(x)=-f'(-x)$.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly right. why is that?

Comment: I have a function such that g(x) = f(x)-f(-x)..

Answer (score 1):

No, that (was originally $f'(-x)=-1·f'(x)$) is not true, just take $f(x)=x$ where you have a constant derivative $f'(x)=1$.

What you can however do is define $f_-(x)=f(-x)$ where then $$f_-'(x)=-f'(-x)$$ and changing the point of the derivative evaluation $$f_-'(-x)=-f'(x).$$

---

In the modified question, the odd function $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$ has the even-symmetric derivative
$$
g'(x)=f'(x)+f'(-x)
$$
which remains unchanged under changing $x$ to $-x$ in all places.